# PHP cookies and session not kept

Tags: php, session, cookies, include

I've been google-ing this for a while, and I have reviewed my code over and over again, still no clue about it.

Here is the deal:

I have a multi-language website. When clicking on a different language preference, I pass it thorugh url as `?lang=en`, or so.

Then, the code uses GET to read the language, start session and creating a cookie named "lang".

Good so far, and actually it was working perfectly.

I was thinking about creating a subdomain, so I got it and I wanted to use the same cookie through the subdomain and i found that I could achive it using (name, value, time, '/', '.domain.com')

It never worked, so I reverted things back to normal: (name, value, time) and that is it. I used to have it with no path or domain values. Actually it is working the same way with a different website.

Long story short, after reverting changes, I am NOT able to get a session or cookie stored in the browser. I have looked in the stored info and there is no such thing as session or cookies for that site.

Answer: YES, I have cookies enabled, plus, my other sites are working perfectly and other public sites using cookies are working fine as well.

I have tried using echo to print the cookie and session value, still no luck.

Here is part of my handle code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    header('Cache-control: private'); // IE 6 FIX

    if(isSet($_GET['lang']))
    {
        $lang = $_GET['lang'];

        // register the session and set the cookie
        $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;

        setcookie("lang", $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
    }
    else if(isSet($_SESSION['lang']))
    {
        $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
    }
    else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang']))
    {
        $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
    }
    else
    {
        $lang = 'es';
    }

    switch ($lang) {
        case 'en':
            $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';
            $lang_dir = 'en';
            break;
        case 'es':
            $lang_file = 'lang.es.php';
            $lang_dir = 'es';
            break;
        default:
            $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';
    }

    include_once 'languages/'.$lang_file;
?>
```

This one is actually working, since I am using this and works:

```
<?php
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    if (!empty($page)) {
        $content .='html/'. $lang['DIR_PATH']. '/'. $page. '.html';
        include($content);
    }
    else {
        include('html/'. $lang['DIR_PATH']. '/'. 'home.html');
    }
?>
```

Using the link

```
index.php?lang=en
```

The previous code reads the "en" value, but as soon as I click any link, it is changed to "es".

If include file would not be working, the $lang['DIR_PATH'] would not work and no content would be displayed. Do you agree? Or am I wrong? But it does and changes language succesfully. The thing is that I can not keep the preference stored.

Thanks in advance

Comment: My guess is that you're dealing with conflicted cookies. You probably have two cookies, one for the subdomain and one for the domain. One may overwrite the other. Try deleting all your cookies for this domain and subdomain.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply and for your time.
Actually I tried that, clearing cookies and any site cache or storage was completed.

Plus, the subdomain actually is no longer there, in case it caused conflict with anything.

When I review my cookie information, usually it is stored a SESSION item, but nothing this time. The cookies are not even saved. They are created, but somehow they are not saved.

Comment: Try something like this right after your session_start(); : `var_dump($_SESSION); $_SESSION['blah'] = 'test';` Can you see the "blah" entry after the first page load ? Just trying to see if the problem comes from your logic or from session persistance.

Answer (score 0):

Wow!
Finally I double checked everything.
I got the answer already.

I realized that, somehow (don't know why), my **

> php.ini

** file was modified and now was asking for a different path to save the session.

I anyone has this problem, go to php.ini file and look for

```
session.save_path
```

And either create the specific folder, or change the path showing there

Thanks for reading, anyway, for your help and your time.